# Is there any functionality or plugin that login user in laravel when we login in word press

Tags: wordpress, laravel-5

I want to connect the laravel login when I use the login of wordpress and I am using the laravel 5.

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress you can use the [`wp_login`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) hook, and trigger an API in laravel with `user_id` and some `secret token` which you can validate in Laravel and if token is correct you can use Laravel inbuilt function to login user by ID i.e.  [`Auth::loginUsingId(_USER_ID_);`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#other-authentication-methods), and then you can do your stuff.

OR

The Hampel plugin uses WordPress as your authority,

You can use this library from [Hampel](https://packagist.org/packages/hampel/wordpress-auth-laravel)